# Weird ajax error response when alerting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, publish

```
function girisAjaxKontrol() {
var kullanici = { 'kullaniciAdi': $('#username').val(), 'sifre': $('#password').val() };

$.ajax({
    url: '/Giris/GirisGecerliMi',
    type: 'POST',
    data: kullanici,
    success: girisAjaxReturn,
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error.toString());            
    }
});
```

}

Everything works fine when debugging the asp .Net MVC4 project. But, after publish, the code block above returns an alert message as "[object Object]". Why error message is not string, and why it doesn't work after publish?

Comment: The `jQuery` [**api documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on `$.ajax` explains how to capture the error text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .error() event of jQuery.ajax() accepts three arguments:

> the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object,
>   a string describing the type of error that occurred and
>   an optional exception object, if one occurred.
>   - More about jQuery.ajax() [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Your .error() event is accepting one argument which automatically read by jQuery as the jQXHR object. To see it inside the alert, try to do something like this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(error));
```

Or, you might want to return the description of the error:

```
error: function(error, textStatus) {
     alert(textStatus);
}
```

The exception object is only returned if an HTTP error occured.

Answer (score 1):

The `error` event handler for the deferred object returned by `$.ajax()` takes three parameters:

```
error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
```

Since you're declaring only `function (error) { }` for your error handler, you're actually alerting out the original XHR object used in the AJAX call.

If you want to inspect the whole object, you can try `console.log(error)` on your function, or try to transform it into a JSON string using `JSON.stringify(error)`, then alerting that.

Alternatively, you can also inspect the second or third parameters passed into the error handler. Personally I like to sign my errors functions like `function (x,s,e) {}` for brevity.